# Effiecint way to crawl a website

Tags: php, web-crawler

Let's say there is a classifieds site, and the unique URL to each product is just a number like:
`example.com/product/12345/` Now, let's assume that each number gives a result to a different product in the page, and say I want to get scan all URLs and get every info from from the page by extracting information from the ex: `<div id='info'>someinfo</div>` Now I tried to do this with something like

```
$URL = 1000; 

for($i=1; $i < $URL; $i++){
  $content = file_get_contents("http://example.com/products/$i"); 
  $info = //get the exact info from div and 
  file_put_contents('file.txt', $info); 
}
```

Even though this script works somehow, it fails to write more than the first 5 results, before crashing my system due to memory constraints. So, I would like to know how this is done.

I could use the DOM object to get the contents of the divs, but the real problem is how not to have the script freez the page.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: You could try using the cURL library. It is must more efficient in my opinion then using file_get_contents

Comment: You should consider bench marking how long a single request takes. Doing 1000 requests and writing them to a file all at once may time out your script.

Comment: Are you sure you are running into memory problems and not script timeout?  I don't see anything that that would introduce a memory leak, so as long as you have enough memory allocated to hold `$content`, the DOM object you use to derive `$info` and `$info` itself, I would think memory would not be a constraint.  Then again perhaps you are leaving out something from your code example that may be problematic.

Comment: @MikeBrant It is not memory. Sorry, it is script timeout. I confuse the two always. So, I am thinking I should go forcURL? as falconspy has suggested?

Comment: @ANW That will not help.  You simply need to increase the timeout using `set_time_limit()` or via ini settings.

Comment: @MikeBrant But what if the site has a 100 thousand pages, are you sure even `set_time_limit()` can handle that much resources? Isn't there some sort of garbage collection to free some type memory to inside the `for(){...}` for performance boost? I get the feeling it won't run for about an hour, given that is what it takes to download all info without crashing on me again

Comment: @ANW I don't think you have a memory problem.  You are overwriting variables so there isn't any variable sitting there waiting for garbage collection.  `set_time_limit(0)` would allow the script to run for as long as it takes to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend create shell script for such crawler. Then you don't need to care about timeout:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
$url = 1000;
for ($i = 1; $i < $url; ++$i) {
    $content = getContent("http://example.com/products/$i");
    $info = getInfo($content);
    file_put_contents('file.txt', implode("\n", $info), FILE_APPEND);
}

function getContent($url) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
    $curl_error = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $curl_errno === 0 or die("cURL Error ($curl_errno): $curl_error\n");
    //sleep(2); // Pause 2 sec to avoid ban :)
    return $data;
}

function getInfo($content) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($content);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $result = array();
    // Adopt this block for your needs. This is just example 
    $elements = $xpath->query("//*[@id='info']");
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        $result[] = $element->nodeValue;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I havent been able to test this because the online code editor im using doesn't let me give it `$_GET` values, but I would imagine that this is the most simple way to trick PHP into running your code without a time limit. (or something like this)

```
$url = intval($_GET['url']);
if ($url >= 1) {
    $content = file_get_contents("http://example.com/products/$url"); 
    $info = //get the exact info from div and 
    file_put_contents('file.txt', $info);
    ob_end_flush();
    $url--;
    header("Location: ./thisfile.php?url=$url");
}
```

Comment: Don't you mean `while`?

Comment: @raam86 with stuff like this where php will be running for a long time, i prefer to move each different operation into a page load. that could even provide feedback as the process continues. the `header` call will cause the loop